# STM32 FreeRTOS - Tasks with same priority running serial

Tags: c, task, freertos, stm32cubeide

I am starting on the FreeRTOS.
During my first tests I found something not clear for me.

Created 4 tasks with the same priority (osPriorityNormal). All 4 tasks have the same code:

```
void StartDefaultTask(void *argument)
{
/* USER CODE BEGIN 5 */

    uint8_t DebugString[50];
    uint32_t ui32_SysTimer;

/* Infinite loop */
for(;;)
{
      ui32_SysTimer = xTaskGetTickCount();
      snprintf(DebugString, 30, "%10lu : DefaultTask\n", ui32_SysTimer);
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, DebugString, strlen(DebugString), 1000);
      vTaskDelay(500);
}
/* USER CODE END 5 */
}
```

Looking to the output data on the serial monitor, I was expecting to see all 4 tasks being called almost in parallel. Since the 500ms should not block the processing flow.
But they are running in series!

[Same priorities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rcwbr.png)

Changing the priorities than I see the expected behavior.

[Different priorities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mkco0.png)

Why they are not starting in parallel when using the same priority?
Is the vTaskDelay() appropriate to give this minimum time to the task run again?

Thank you.

Comment: snprintf is not freeRTOS friendly

Comment: what do you mean by pararell?

Comment: Unless you enable round robin in config file the system will not give any time to other task unless task passed the control to the sheduler

Comment: Not sure you could see the pictures attached. I mean series one after the other and parallel all 4 starting almost at the same time, just giving the time to print to the serial port. The snprintf is just for debugging purposes, any other recommendation here?

Comment: Are you using CMSIS-RTOS? (this is the default if you're enabling RTOS in STM's Cube IDE) Note that this uses a slightly different RTOS api then usual. I think it's mostly just wrapper functions, but they might do some additional things. Try using the function `osDelay (uint32_t ticks);` instead of `vTaskDelay()`. Here are the docs: https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/RTOS2/html/group__CMSIS__RTOS__Wait.html#gaf6055a51390ef65b6b6edc28bf47322e

Comment: Yes, CMSIS v2. I started with osDelay, same result. I just wonder if this serial processing is expected or I am doing somthing wrong....

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem was in the output to the console.
The `HAL_UART_Transmit` function is getting a busy status and losing some of the data. That is the reason for the serial timing sequency.

One possible solution is to store the data in a buffer and print it to the console only once, in a dedicated task.

Comment: Having only one task accessing a specific hardware is the common & correct practice. So, you should have one task accessing the serial port, collecting print requests from other tasks using a queue.